# Get which fields were modified - before calling Update()

Tags: 2010, development

I need to call `Update()` on an item only if some fields were modified, and some other fields were not modified.

Is there anyway to get, programmatically, a list or array with the names of the fields that were modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an event receiver, you have the BeforeProperties and AfterProperties, as well as the list item - there is some weirdness in when they are set based on the exact event, documented [here](http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.ca/2012/09/dismistifying-afterproperties.html)

Outside of an event receiver, your best bet is probably to keep track yourself. If that's not possible, I think retrieving a fresh copy of the item from the database and comparing the fields would work. `SPListItem originalItem = list.GetItemById(item.Id)`

Comment: Thanks. Comparing the instance of the item with another one just fetched from the database works.